# Are questions on zoologists bio on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions

Can I ask questions about famous zoologist and biologists biographies or lives here, if they have very little or actually no impact on actual biology?

For example, I'd like to know why [Edward Turner Bennett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Turner_Bennett), English zoologist, died at an early age (39 years) and whether his death had any connection to his work (e.g., perhaps killed by some animal or as an effect of some disease while on a scientific journey)?

Or are such questions considered off-topic for this site?

Comment: hmm matter to think. looks off-topic but Is there exists a biography site

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such questions are off-topic here because they are not really about biology. Such questions may be asked in 
[History of Science and Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com) SE.